Is there any pattern in storage value of integer declared variables that are not initialized in C
I just started reading the book
by K N King called
C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn 2008,
and I have an exercise:

Write a program that declares several int and float variables, without initializing them, and then prints their values. Is there any pattern to the values? (Usually there isn't.)

I run this code in Dev C++ 5.11
My code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,a1,a2,a3;
    float x,y,z,x1,x2,x3;
    
    printf("a:%d ,b:%d ,c:%d ,d:%d ,e:%d ,f:%d ,a1:%d ,a2:%d ,a3:%d \n x:%f ,y:%f ,z:%f ,x1:%f ,x2:%f ,x3:%f",a,b,c,d,e,f,a1,a2,a3,x,y,z,x1,x2,x3);
}

Result that I got:

At least in older C and C++ it's up to the compiler implementation to decide, and just to confuse you debug builds might behave differently than release builds.  I've used compilers where debug set everything to 0 but release was random garbage.  The point of the exercise was to teach you that you can't count on any specific values.

By release you mean output function?

No, there are build flags for making an executable - debug includes extra information for the debugger and supports breakpoints based on the source code lines instead of assembly code, release usually does not.

Oh I get it ,thank you!

This program has undefined behavior because the variables are used uninitialized and they could have been declared register. It's not correct to think that the only possible result of this program is printing some random numbers -- the standard defines no meaning to the program. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368/1400793

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?  The output is plain text; it should be treated as code. Also note that the spaces around the newline escape sequence in the printf() format string are not desirable — trailing white space should be avoided, and the leading white space on the second line is inconsistent with the first line. You could consider using two printf() statements, one for each line of output. The code would be more readable that way. In general, spaces go after commas, not before.

This is a horrible exercise. There are patterns, in that behaviors of compilers and hardware and other things will cause various results depending on characteristics of those compilers and such, but one could not expect a student to perceive those relationships just from uncontrolled experiments like this, and it does not teach you proper C semantics. Stop using that book.


Is there any pattern in storage value of integer declared variables that are not initialized in C

There is no specified pattern.

The output seen is expected to be very implementation dependent.
It may be inconsistent from run to run.
History of prior processor use may come into play too.
If expectations are low, this is an interesting exercise.
IOWs, don't read to much into the results.

Side issue: output format

Is there any pattern to the values? (Usually there isn't.)

Using "%f" to investigate this issue is a poor choice as nearly 50% of all possible float values will print as 0.000000 or -0.000000.  Thus a pattern may exist and output fails to demo it.
Instead use "%a" or if decimal output is obliged, use %g.
Deeper
NAN payload is another issue.
I'd consider printing the byte values pattern for all FP and integer objects for a deeper investigation.
unsigned char buf[sizeof some_variabale];
memcpy(buf, &some_variabale, sizeof buf);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof buf; i++) {
  printf("%02X", buf[i]);
}

Yet using memcpy() to retrieve the some_variabale object versus printf() may alter the uninitialized value printed.
Moral of the story
@Dave S good comment:
"The point of the exercise was to teach you that you can't count on any specific values. – "
This implies:
the results may be very different from run to run
and
the results may be exactly the same from run to run.  Thus not a good source of random bits.


Is there any pattern in storage value of integer declared variables that are not initialized in C

Actually, there is one pretty regular pattern.
If you expect (perhaps because you read it somewhere on the net) that the values will be random from run to run, you will discover that they are always exactly the same.
But if for some reason you get it into your head that you can predict the values, they won't be, in that case they'll be utterly random.
I call this pattern — that, no matter what, your expectation is always wrong — the Law of Confounding Expectations of Uninitialized Local Variables in C.
